# Hard limiting / threshold activation function in TensorFlow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm trying to implement a basic, binary [Hopfield Network](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Hopfield_network) in TensorFlow 0.9. Unfortunately I'm having a very hard time getting the activation function working. I'm looking to get the very simple `If net[i] < 0, output[i] = 0, else output[i] = 1` but everything I've tried seems to remove the gradient, i.e. I get the "No gradients provided for any variable" exception when trying to implement the training op.

For example, I tried casting `tf.less()` to `float`, I tried doing something along the lines of

```
tf.maximum(tf.minimum(net, 0) + 1, 0)
```

but I forgot about small decimal values. Finally I did

```
tf.maximum(tf.floor(tf.minimum(net, 0) + 1), 0)
```

but `tf.floor` doesn't register gradients. I also tried replacing the floor with a cast to int and then a cast back to float but same deal.

Any suggestions on what I could do?

Comment: The result of `If net[i] < 0, output[i] = 0, else output[i] = 1` has a gradient of 0. everywhere (no gradient in 0.)

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot Ah dip, looks like I need to take a calc 1 refresher, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using tf.nn.sigmoid() or tf.nn.tanh()?  They are differentible functions that behave somewhat like you describe.

Comment: I am not sure about registering gradients, but did you try `tf.round` along with `tf.add` ?

Comment: Well so the main issue was I was trying to use backprop on an activation function with a gradient of 0, and backprop uses the gradient of the activation function to calculate the error term. The network I was using at the time required binary output so I couldn't use sigmoid or the like. I was really new to TF when I wrote this so I just didn't even think of writing my own training ops. So the initial question of getting binary output is answered below, but actually training a network with a binary threshold activation function can't be done with the build in gradient descent ops in TF.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

a bit late, but if anyone needs it, I used this definition

```
def binary_activation(x):

    cond = tf.less(x, tf.zeros(tf.shape(x)))
    out = tf.where(cond, tf.zeros(tf.shape(x)), tf.ones(tf.shape(x)))

    return out
```

with x being a tensor

Comment: fyi, you can let tensorflow broadcast values, e.g.: `tf.where(x > 1., x, 0.)` for activation with threshold of `1` or `tf.where(x > 1., 1., 0.)` for binary activation with threshold of `1`

Answer (score 5):

Just for the record, one can get the *sign function* via `tf.sign`. It outputs a float or integer (depending on the input) indicating the sign with `-1` or `1`. However, note that `tf.sign(0) == 0`!

For a *hard limiting activation function*, *binary threshold activation function*, *Heaviside step function*, see the other answer.