# How to produce a one-hot output in keras?

Tags: python, keras

Normally, there's no need to produce a one hot vector output in a neural network; however, I am trying to train a GAN, so the output of one network needs to match the input of the other. Currently the last layer in my generator is a dense softmax, so that I have a probability distribution over the outputs, but I need to convert that vector to a one-hot, so it matches the input the discriminator expects. There doesn't seem to be any built in layer to do this with keras. I'm trying to write a lambda expression, but can't seem to get it to work.

Here is the code right now:

```
    s1 = Input(shape=(self.sentence_length,))

    embed = Embedding(output_dim=self.embedding_vector_length,
            input_dim=self.vocabulary_size,
            input_length=self.sentence_length)(s1)
    x = concatenate([embed,embed],axis=1)
    x = LSTM(self.latent_dimension,return_sequences=True)(x)
    x = LSTM(self.embedding_vector_length,return_sequences=True)(x)
    x = Lambda(lambda s: s[:,15:,:])(x)
    x = Dense(self.vocabulary_size,activation='softmax')(x)
    # x = Lambda(???)
    model = Model(s1,x)
    model.summary()
```

Comment: Just change the input of the discriminator to take one-hot, you don't need a lambda.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear. The discriminator already accepts a one-hot vector. The code shown is for the generator. The output of the generator needs to feed into the discriminator.

Comment: Your generator is already outputting a probability vector with softmax, so the code you already have should be fine

Comment: A probability vector is different from a one-hot vector. Since the actual training data for the GAN will be one-hot vectors, the output of the generator must also be one-hot to match.

Comment: I would look into a binary activation function instead of a lambda layer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743574/hard-limiting-threshold-activation-function-in-tensorflow/42163394?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa.

Comment: Check out this related question, maybe it will help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51040950/custom-loss-in-keras-with-softmax-to-one-hot/51065067#51065067