# Keras Custom Loss for One-Hot Encoded

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I currently have a DNN I trained that makes a prediction of a one-hot encoded classification for states that a game is in. Essentially, imagine there are three states, `0, 1, or 2.`

Now, I normally would use `categorical_cross_entropy` for the loss function, but I realized not all classifications are not equal for my states. For example:

- If the model predicts it should be state 1, there is no cost to my system if that classification is wrong, since state 1 is basically do nothing, so reward 0x.
- If the model **correctly** predict states 0 or 2 (i.e. predict = 2 and correct = 2), then that reward should be 3x.
- If the model **incorrectly** predict states 0 or 2 (i.e. predict = 2 and correct = 0), then that reward should be -1x.

I know that we can declare our custom loss functions in Keras but I keep on getting stuck with forming it. Anyone have suggestions how to transform that pseudo code? I can't tell how I'd do that in a vector-wise operation.

**Additional question**: I essentially am after a reward function I think. Is this the same as a loss function? Thanks!

```
def custom_expectancy(y_expected, y_pred):
    
    # Get 0, 1 or 2
    expected_norm = tf.argmax(y_expected);
    predicted_norm = tf.argmax(y_pred);
    
    # Some pseudo code....
    # Now, if predicted == 1
    #     loss += 0
    # elif predicted == expected
    #     loss -= 3
    # elif predicted != expected
    #     loss += 1
    #
    # return loss
```

Sources consulted:

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/55215/how-do-i-create-a-keras-custom-loss-function-for-a-one-hot-encoded-binary-classi

[Custom loss in Keras with softmax to one-hot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51040950/custom-loss-in-keras-with-softmax-to-one-hot)

**Code Update**

```
import tensorflow as tf
def custom_expectancy(y_expected, y_pred):
    
    # Get 0, 1 or 2
    expected_norm = tf.argmax(y_expected);
    predicted_norm = tf.argmax(y_pred);
    
    results = tf.unstack(expected_norm)
    
    # Some pseudo code....
    # Now, if predicted == 1
    #     loss += 0
    # elif predicted == expected
    #     loss += 3
    # elif predicted != expected
    #     loss -= 1
    
    for idx in range(0, len(expected_norm)):
        predicted = predicted_norm[idx]
        expected = expected_norm[idx]
        
        if predicted == 1: # do nothing
            results[idx] = 0.0
        elif predicted == expected: # reward
            results[idx] = 3.0
        else: # wrong, so we lost
            results[idx] = -1.0
    
    
    return tf.stack(results)
```

I *think* this is what I'm after, but I haven't quite figured out how to build the correct tensor (which should be of size batch) to return.

Answer (score 1):

[Here there is a nice post explaining the concepts of the loss function and cost function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179026/objective-function-cost-function-loss-function-are-they-the-same-thing). Multiple answers illustrate how they are considered by different authors in the field of machine learning.

As for the loss function, you may find [the following implementation useful](https://gist.github.com/wassname/ce364fddfc8a025bfab4348cf5de852d). It implements a weighted cross-entropy loss, where you weigh each class proportionally to their weight in train. This could be adapted to satisfy the constraints specified above.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to build a conditional custom loss is to use `tf.keras.backend.switch` without involving loops.

In your case, you should combine 2 *switch* conditional expressions to obtain the desired results.

The desired loss function can be reproduced in this way:

```
def custom_expectancy(y_expected, y_pred):
    
    zeros = tf.cast(tf.reduce_sum(y_pred*0, axis=-1), tf.float32) ### important to produce gradient
    y_expected = tf.cast(tf.reshape(y_expected, (-1,)), tf.float32)
    class_pred = tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
    class_pred = tf.cast(class_pred, tf.float32)
    
    cond1 = (class_pred != y_expected) & (class_pred != 1)
    cond2 = (class_pred == y_expected) & (class_pred != 1)
    
    res1 = tf.keras.backend.switch(cond1, zeros -1, zeros)
    res2 = tf.keras.backend.switch(cond2, zeros +3, zeros)
    
    return res1 + res2
```

Where `cond1` is when the model incorrectly predicts states 0 or 2 and `cond2` is when the model correctly predicts states 0 or 2. The standard states is zero that is returned when `cond1` and `cond2` are not activated.

You can notice that `y_expected` can be passed as a simple tensor/array of integer encoded states (**no need to one-hot them**).

Here how the loss function works:

```
true = tf.constant([[1],    [2],    [1],    [0]    ])  ## no need to one-hot
pred = tf.constant([[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,1],[0,1,0]])

custom_expectancy(true, pred)
```

Which returns:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([ 0.,  3., -1.,  0.], dtype=float32)>
```

That seems to be consistent with our needs.

To use the loss inside a model:

```
X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (1000,10))
y = np.random.randint(0,3, (1000)) ## no need to one-hot

model = Sequential([Dense(3, activation='softmax')])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=custom_expectancy)
model.fit(X,y, epochs=3)
```

[Here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1__fy-NoN8phcUreBdEwGjsGnhVjI-Rip?usp=sharing) the running notebook

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you want to do it. If your ground truth y_true is dense (shaped N3), you can use a `tf.reduce_all(y_true == [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], axis=-1, keepdims=True)` and `tf.reduce_all(y_true == [1.0, 0.0, 0.0], axis=-1, keepdims=True)` to control the if/elif/else. You could further optimize this with a tf.gather.

```
def sparse_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  """Calculate loss for game. Follows keras loss signature.
  
  Args:
    y_true: Sparse tensor of shape N1, where correct prediction
      is encoded as 0, 1, or 2. 
    y_pred: Tensor of shape N3. For each row, the three columns
      represent the predicted probability of each state. 
      For example, [0.1, 0.4, 0.6] means, "There's a 10% chance the 
      right state is 0; 40% chance the right state is 1, 
      and 60% chance the right state is 2". 
  """

  # This is the unvectorized implementation on individual rows which is more
  # intuitive. But TF requires vectorization. 
  # if y_true == 0:
  #   # Value matrix is shape 3. Broadcasting will occur. 
  #   return -tf.reduce_sum(y_pred * [3.0, 0.0, -1.0])
  # elif y_true == 2:
  #   return -tf.reduce_sum(y_pred * [-1.0, 0.0, 3.0])
  # else:
  #   # According to the rules, this is never the correct
  #   # state the predict so it should never show up.
  #   assert False, f'Impossible state reached. y_true: {y_true}, y_pred: {y_pred}.'


  # We vectorize by calculating the reward for all predictions for two cases:
  # if y_true is zero or if y_true is two. To eliminate this inefficiency, we 
  # could us tf.gather to build an N3 shaped matrix to multiply against. 
  reward_for_true_zero = tf.reduce_sum(y_pred * [3.0, 0.0, -1.0], axis=-1, keepdims=True) # N1
  reward_for_true_two = tf.reduce_sum(y_pred * [-1.0 ,0.0, 3.0], axis=-1, keepdims=True) # N1

  reward = tf.where(y_true == 0.0, reward_for_true_zero, reward_for_true_one) # N1
  return -tf.reduce_sum(reward)
```