# Custom binarize (thresholding) image layer in TensorFlow 2.2

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow2.0

I am building a CNN in Tensorflow whose output needs to be a binary image (0, 1). I'd like to implement a custom layer with a single tunable variable (threshold) that will format the final image, e.g.:

```
>>> a
array([[ 0.02 ,  0.833,  0.778,  0.87 ],
       [ 0.979,  0.799,  0.461,  0.781],
       [ 0.118,  0.64 ,  0.143,  0.945],
       [ 0.522,  0.415,  0.265,  0.774]])

>>> np.where(a > threshold, 1, 0) 
array([[0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1]])
```

I have attempted to implement this as:

```
class BinarizeLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BinarizeLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.threshold = tf.Variable(initial_value=0.5, dtype=tf.float32, name='BinaryThreshold')

    def call(self, x):
        cond = tf.math.less(x, tf.fill(tf.shape(x), self.threshold))
        out = tf.where(cond, tf.zeros(tf.shape(x)), tf.ones(tf.shape(x)))
        return out
```

However, this results in `ValueError: An operation has 'None' for gradient.`. Is there a way around this? I have tried adding tf.stop_gradient() to all of the parts of "call", but the error persists.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743574/hard-limiting-threshold-activation-function-in-tensorflow The comment by OP in this question implies it "cannot be done" but that was several years ago.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to implement custom layer, it is already supported by tensorflow
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where

```
tf.where(a > threshold, 1, 0)
```